# Laravel custom action url in mail notification

Tags: php, laravel

I've got question about mail notifications in Laravel 5.5.

CustomNotification.php in function `toMail()` i use this:

```
->action('Open myapp', url('myapp://test'))
```

If I send mail I've got empty `href` tag (`style` and `class` works).

How to use *myapp://* instead *http://* to create action in mail notification?

It has to work like:
[image]

Comment: Does http:// works?

Comment: Yes, http://example.com works (external link). If i add 'test' in url() it'll be ex. 127.0.0.1/test but i need to create href="myapp://"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mails cut (probably security reason) the custom URL's (like `myapp://test`).
You can resolve that if you create landing page and then put button with custom URL (in mail have to put landing page URL).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`forceSchema`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_forceSchema) method:

```
$urlGenerator = url();
$urlGenerator->forceSchema('myapp'); // forceScheme() for laravel 5.4+ 
$url = $urlGenerator->to('test');
```

Comment: It's give me myapp://127.0.0.1/test and still href tag doesn't exists.
If I use:
$urlGenerator->forceScheme('myapp');
$url = $urlGenerator->to('myapp://test');
then I've got correct link, but don't have href tag

Comment: Check your generated mail template before sending. It may be that mail service itself cuts out your `href` attribute as suspicious